# Ruby on Rails: How to run things in the background?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background-process

When a new resource is created and it needs to do some **lengthy processing** before the resource is ready, how do I send that processing away **into the background** where it *won't hold up* the current request or other traffic to my web-app?

in my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 after_save :background_check

 protected
 def background_check
  # check through a list of 10000000000001 mil different
  # databases that takes approx one hour :)
  if( check_for_record_in_www( self.username ) )
    # code that is run after the 1 hour process is finished.
    user.update_attribute( :has_record )
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should definitely check out the following Railscasts:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/128-starling-and-workling
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/129-custom-daemon
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq

They explain how to run background processes in Rails in every possible way (with or without a queue ...)

Comment: These days, the most-used/best-supported options are [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque), and [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). IMHO, Sidekiq is the best one for high-throughput queues, and delayed_job is the best one for very low throughput.

Comment: Another option is [IronWorker](http://www.iron.io) if you want background processing "as a service" and never have to worry about the idea of servers or queuing. IronMQ/IronWorker also offers auto retries, task logs, webhooks, etc. It integrates nicely with Rails. Here are some videos: https://www.youtube.com/user/ironiodevelopers

Comment: Useful links and still applicable after these years but it doesn't summarize them or answer the question directly.

Answer (score 8):

I've just been experimenting with the 'delayed_job' gem because it works with the Heroku hosting platform and it was ridiculously easy to setup!!

Add gem to Gemfile, `bundle install`, `rails g delayed_job`, `rake db:migrate`
Then start a queue handler with;

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
```

Where you have a method call which is your lengthy process i.e

```
company.send_mail_to_all_users
```

you change it to;

```
company.delay.send_mail_to_all_users
```

Check the full docs on github: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Answer (score 7):

Start a separate process, which is probably most easily done with `system`, prepending a 'nohup' and appending an '&' to the end of the command you pass it. (Make sure the command is just one string argument, not a list of arguments.)

There are several reasons you want to do it this way, rather than, say, trying to use threads:

1. Ruby's threads can be a bit tricky when it comes to doing I/O; you have to take care that some things you do don't cause the entire process to block.
2. If you run a program with a different name, it's easily identifiable in 'ps', so you don't accidently think it's a FastCGI back-end gone wild or something, and kill it.

Really, the process you start should be "deamonized," see the [Daemonize](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/) class for help.

Answer (score 2):

you ideally want to use an existing background job server, rather than writing your own. these will typically let you submit a job and give it a unique key; you can then use the key to periodically query the jobserver for the status of your job without blocking your webapp. [here is a nice roundup](http://www.tobinharris.com/past/2009/3/9/6-ways-to-run-background-jobs-in-rubyonrails/) of the various options out there.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use backgroundrb, its nice it allows you to communicate to it during long processes. So you can have status updates in your rails app

Answer (score 1):

I think [spawn](http://github.com/tra/spawn) is a great way to fork your process, do some processing in background, and show user just some confirmation that this processing was started.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
def background_check
   exec("script/runner check_for_record_in_www.rb #{self.username}") if fork == nil
end
```

The program "`check_for_record_in_www.rb`" will then run in another process and will have access to ActiveRecord, being able to access the database.