# how to run background job in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a small application that I would like to host on Heroku. All the application do is log in to a remote server every 5 minutes to get a file and analyze it.

I am using rails3 and wondering how can I make it run background job like this.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 3):

See:

http://docs.heroku.com/background-jobs

Also:

[Ruby on Rails: How to run things in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897605/ruby-on-rails-how-to-run-things-in-the-background)

Answer (score 0):

also: 
[Resque Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque)

Heroku has a lot of documentation on scaling up workers, and there are gems for only using workers while your processes need them, thus saving you a ton of money.