# loading each file in directory and running a function from that file in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to scrape concert data from a bunch of different websites.  I've written several scripts, each of which scrapes data from a particular website and organizes it into a hash with a predictable structure.  Each of these scripts has the function `scrape` to accomplish this.  I have all of these scraper scripts in a directory.  I want to then write a master script which, for each script in the directory, calls that script's `scrape` and adds the data into the database.

I plan on making this master script a Resque worker such that the site will scrape each site in the background daily.

How do I accomplish this in the master script?  Right now I go through the directory like so:

```
Dir.glob(/app/workers/scraped_venues/*.rb) do |venue_scraper|
  # call that script's `scrape` function
  # use data from that `scrape` call
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make a rake task that does the scraping:

Rake tutorial: http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial

and use the whenever gem to run the scraping each day. Should be painfully easy to figure out from docs:

https://github.com/javan/whenever

How to run things in the background in rails: [Ruby on Rails: How to run things in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897605/ruby-on-rails-how-to-run-things-in-the-background)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Would I put the rake task in Rakefile?  And I'm assuming the task should still call a Resque worker so that the task is done in the background?

Also, just FYI, Whenever is a great gem but doesn't play so nice with Heroku, the scheduler add-on is much easier.

Comment: Also! Forgot the main issue for me.  As I don't know in advance what venues I'm scraping, I won't know the name of the classes held in each scraper script.  So how do I handle this?  EG a script might be CBGB_sraper.rb that holds the scrape function inside a CBGBScraper class, but my rake task won't know that..

Comment: ^ i feel like there might be an easier way to organize that? and you put rake tasks in lib/tasks

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. What if each of the scripts doesn't actually hold a class, but is just a script (no functions)?

Comment: are you asking how to run ruby code? You could put it in a module and call it, reopening the module for each site's specific parser; you could run the files using the command line arguments within ruby with backticks the equivalent to `$ ruby path/ruby_file.rb`; you could require each script and use some metaprogramming; you could put it all in a gem and update the gem when needed... it depends

Comment: thanks AJcodez, still having trouble but I'll accept your answer for now at least.  much appreciated